# Laravel Lumen cannot recognize table in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, lumen

I have a problem when I make a request on my Laravel server

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbdespensa.imagenesProducto' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `imagenesProducto` where `productoId` = 5)

I have the imagenesProducto table but laravel didnt recognize it

Thanks  and help :)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\ImagenesProducto;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
class ImagenesProductoController extends Controller
 {
    function getImagesByProduct(Request $request,$id){
    if($request-> isJson()){
        try{
            $images = ImagenesProducto::where('productoId','=',$id)->get();
            return response()->json($images,200);
        }catch(ModelNotFoundException $e){
            return response()->json("error"=>"error",500);
        }
    }else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unhatorized'], 401, []);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show us the request you're making.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/server/getcarousel/5 this is the request adn the server send me the error in the detail

Answer (score 0):

Are other database queries successful? (if not you should check .env file for db config)

Or maybe you have problem in model. You should specify table name in model.

```
class ImagenesProducto extends Model{
public $table = "imagenesProducto";
```

Comment: The error started when I upload my app server into a cpanel because when I was coding in localhost the server works perfectly

Comment: I guess you should update .env file with "live database" host, db name, user name and pass

Comment: Actually, I updated my .env file already, also  the client side can request all tables without the table imagenesProducto. I used dd()  and the error starts when I make query with conditional   ::where

Comment: What about other queries? I mean are you sure db connection is successful. You should also check your model file as I show.

Comment: Yes, the model is equal than you show me 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ImagenesProducto extends Model 
{
    public $table = 'imagenesProducto';
    public $primaryKey = 'idImgProd';
    public $fillable = ['nombreImgProd','detalleImgProd','pathImgProd'];
    public $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at','productoId','precioImgProd'];

Comment: **What about other queries? I mean are you sure db connection is successful?**

Comment: Yes , Look this is the domain that is upload the server with the cliente and it works www.despensaweb.com . All product shown in the page are in the database

Comment: Do you have record **productoId = 5** in imagenesProducto table ?

Comment: you have the reason , my class model had the wrong table name because when I upload the  databse on the cpanel, mysql  has being change  the name of the table imagenesProducto to  imagenesproducto. I am a dumbass lol. Thnks for your help